# What are the similarity and difference between quantum fidelity estimation and parameter estimation problem?

Tags: quantum-information, estimation, metrology

Quantum fidelity estimation is to estimate the similarity between two quantum states or process. Could quantum fidelity be viewd as a parameter? And what are the similarity and difference between quantum fidelity estimation and parameter estimation problem?

---

***[Cross-posted on qc.SE](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/33390/55)***